# How can I display images for each data in the table

Tags: php, database, image

I have a table where I store some teams. I am displaying them in the page via Materialize cards tag. What I want to do is to display for every team their badge.

### Displaying teams

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "proiect");
$sql1 = "SELECT id_club, nume, avatar FROM club";
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($qry1)) {
   echo "<div class='w3-card b'>";
   echo "<a href='echipa?id=" . $row1['id_club'] . "' _target='blank' title='Vezi echipa'><img src='img/referees.jpg' alt='Person' style='width:100%'>";
   echo "<div class='w3-container'>";
   echo "<h4><a href='echipa?id=" . $row1['id_club'] . "' _target='blank' title='Vezi echipa'><b>" . $row1['nume'] . "</b></h4>";
   echo "</div>";
   echo "</div>";
}
```

Now it is hardcoded the image that is displayed. I want the badge team image to have the same name as the club name from the database.

Comment: Maybe not a laravel question - you may wish to edit and remove the tag

Answer (score 0):

If the file is stored in img folder with same name then this code will work.

```
    <?php
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "proiect");
        $sql1 = "SELECT id_club, nume, avatar FROM club";
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($qry1)) {
               echo "<div class='w3-card b'>";
               echo "<a href='echipa?id=" . $row1['id_club'] . "' _target='blank' title='Vezi echipa'><img src='img/'.$row1['nume'].'.jpg' alt='Person' style='width:100%'>";
               echo "<div class='w3-container'>";
               echo "<h4><a href='echipa?id=" . $row1['id_club'] . "' _target='blank' title='Vezi echipa'><b>" . $row1['nume'] . "</b></h4>";
               echo "</div>";
               echo "</div>";
               }
?>
```